# Constant height and depth of hyperref link boxes

Tags: hyperref, links, height

For boxes around links which the `hyperref` package creates, their height/depth seems to be dependent on the maximum height and depth not of letters *of the enclosed material* (see top example pair below) but of letters *on the same line* (see bottom example pair below).

It would be nice to

1. make the height/depth of link boxes dependent on only the enclosed material or
2. make the height/depth of link boxes constant (maybe something with height x⋅`\baselineskip` and depth (1-x)⋅`\baselineskip`).

How can I achieve option 2? (Answers for option 1 are welcome too, but I will mark as "the" answer only one that does option 2.)

[image: hyperref link boxes]

(This difference in vertical dimension(s) seems to be viewer-independent.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{dy}
dy.\footnote{Footnote.} \smash{\rule[-0.3\baselineskip]{1em}{\baselineskip}}

\section{abc}
ac.\footnote{Footnote.} \smash{\rule[-0.3\baselineskip]{1em}{\baselineskip}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: they are horrible anyway use `[hidelinks]` and they go away:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle David! Their use is to indicate where clicking will lead you elsewhere; in their absence there will be nasty surprises for the unsuspecting lay user. That said, you have a point :-) and I think that it should be an easily accessible option in the `pdf`-viewer to either make invisible or disable those boxes.

Comment: Yes but you can use colour or underlining (and in most pdf readers the cursor changes anyway) _nothing_ other than hyperref generated documents ever uses a full 4 sided box.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I gladly admit you have a point. If it's technically possible, one could highlight two opposing corners (or just one corner) in an inconspicuous color. Using a different textcolor works, though not for documents to be printed. (The `hyperref` boxes do go away when printed, I think.) Something like underlining is indeed good. (Note to others: My OP/question remains.)

Comment: If you think my comments are discouraging answers, I'll delete. I was only chatting really.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, not at all :-) I thought your comment was kinda funny, actually.

Comment: having just struggled with a smartphone panel on which an essential link was *not* clearly highlighted (not a tex page), i plead for nonremoval of such highlights.  yes, they're ugly, but in many cases vital.  work instead toward making their appearance less offensive and maximally informative.  (it's a good thing that what i was trying to accomplish was not an emergency.)

Comment: A short box simulating a button is not so bad, but a table of contents with boxes is unsightly and annoying to read. Moreover, today most people understand that a blue chunk of text in a electronic format, even in PDF, surely is a  link.

Answer (score 8):

Link boxing is very driver dependent, compare with dvips/ps2pdf:

> [image: dvips/ps2pdf]

### pdfTeX

Package `hyperref` uses `\pdfstartlink` and `\pdfendlink` for the link and lets pdfTeX determine the rectangle dimensions; pdfTeX just uses the height/depth of the surrounding box.

- Advantage is automatic line breaking of links.
- Disadvantage: height and/or depth of the rectangle can be way too large, e.g.:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \begin{document}
  \section{Foo}\label{foo}

  \noindent
  \vrule width 5pt height 3\baselineskip depth 2\baselineskip
  \hyperref[foo]{abc}
  \mbox{\hyperref[foo]{abc}}

  \end{document}
  ```

  > [image: pdfTeX]

  A workaround is also shown, boxing the link in `\mbox`. But this prevents line breaks.

An additional depth for the links can be added by `\vphantom{y}` in the example of the question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{dy}
dy.\footnote{Footnote.}
\smash{\rule[-0.3\baselineskip]{1em}{\baselineskip}}

\section{abc\protect\vphantom{y}}  
ac.\footnote{Footnote.}\vphantom{y}
\smash{\rule[-0.3\baselineskip]{1em}{\baselineskip}}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Something like `\vphantom{y}` could be added to the links, but there are languages with accented letter, `\vphantom{y\"A}`; oh, no, the author of pdfTeX is even written with a double accent and soon previously normal link rectangles would look quite ridiculous with large heights and depths.

Also adding `\vphantom` to ensure a minimum height/depth does not work everywhere. `\vphantom` can be added at the begin and end of a link, but
if a link is broken across lines, then this will not apply to the middle lines of the link.

Comment: There is one thing that one can do: set the height of link boxes uniformly to that of `\vphantom{Iy}` or maybe `\vphantom{\"Uy}`. That could be a `hyperref` option.