# Unpleasant high frames of citation or reference in paragraphs

Tags: hyperref

When both a citation (or reference of equations) and a math object appear in the same line in a paragraph, the frame of the citation is higher than normal. Any ideas how to fix this but keep the frame? Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[round]{natbib} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\begin{document} 
Since $X_n\overset{p}{\to}X$ as $n\to\infty$, we then have... 

\end{document}
```

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Thanks but I want to keep the frames.

Comment: Sorry, then it wasn't clear from your question.  Can you post a minimal example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: That's my fault. Here is a simple example:                 \documentclass[a4paper, 11 pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs,amsfonts}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Since $X_n\overset{L}{\to}X$ as $n\to\infty$, by \citet{Davydov1998local}, we then have...



\bibliography{D:/Dropbox/Common/mybibliography}

\end{document}

Comment: You can edit your question to include the example (I've done that for you); however, since the same problem arises with a reference to an equation, you could make the problem more self-contained by not using a citation in the example.  Or see [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) for how to include a sample `.bib` file in your example.

Comment: Thank you! The reason I didn't include a reference to an equation is that I believe the problem is on the hyperref package not the way I refer or cite, when a math object appears on the same line. Therefore, the same problem arises if you refer to a theorem, lemma or corollary.

Comment: I understand that, and you are correct, but your document as given won't compile for anyone but you, whereas one with a reference to an equation, which will show the same effect, will compile for everyone.

Comment: Here's another relevant question: [Constant height and depth of hyperref link boxes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176214). If you put the citation in an `\mbox` it will go back to the normal height.  Not an ideal solution in the general case, though, but it's not clear there's a better one.

Comment: I am not a proficient LaTeX user. Making the MWEB work seems hard to me. If people understand my question, that is fine; if not, just forget it. Seems not worth spending more time on this AND I appreciate your help and time!

Answer (score 5):

The size of links is dependent on the size of other things in the same line (roughly) as the link, and so since your inline math causes the line height to be larger (which it does) then the box will be larger. For a more detailed discussion of the problem, see the following question:

- [Constant height and depth of hyperref link boxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176214/2693)

As a workaround, you can put your citation or reference into an `\mbox` but this will have the problem of not allowing the link to break across lines, yielding overfull boxes.  Here's an example of this. (This is also an example of how to make a minimal example with a bibliography.)

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !BIB TS-program = bibtex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}    
@article{Westerstahl1998,
    Author = {D Westerstahl},
    Journal = {Linguistics and Philosophy},
    Pages = {635-643},
    Title = {On Mathematical Proofs of the Vacuity of Compositionality (Remarks On {Kazmi} and {Pelletier}, {`Is Compositionality Formally Vacuous?'})},
    Volume = {21},
    Year = {1998}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{kluwer}
\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt

This is a line that contains a reference \cite{Westerstahl1998}.

This is a line that contains $X_n\overset{L}{\to}X$ as $n\to\infty$ and a reference \cite{Westerstahl1998}.

This is a line that contains $X_n\overset{L}{\to}X$ as $n\to\infty$ and a reference \mbox{\cite{Westerstahl1998}}.

\setlength{\emergencystretch}{2.5em} This is a line that contains $X_n\overset{L}{\to}X$ as $n\to\infty$ and a reference \mbox{\cite{Westerstahl1998}}. 
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

This document produces the following warning because the `\mbox` containing the citation overlaps into the right margin.  We can cause the line to wrap by increasing the `\emergency` stretch but this will make the math look quite ugly, as in the fourth line.

```
Overfull \hbox (6.43889pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 27--1
```

[image: output of code]